# Can't change combobox background color at Ext 3.2.1

Tags: extjs, combobox

Hey I'm trying to create a color picker, and I would like to change the combo box background when the user selects the color that he wants.

I'm calling this function: setStyle(), to set the combobox style, but I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).setStyle is not a function
    at Object.fn (...js?v=1510223645:210)
    at EXTUTIL.Event.fire (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:1735)
    at J.fireEvent (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:1484)
    at J.onSelect (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:39222)
    at J.onViewClick (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:39309)
    at EXTUTIL.Event.fire (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:1735)
    at J.fireEvent (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:1484)
    at J.onClick (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:27169)
    at HTMLDivElement.h (ext-all.js?v=1510223645:2158)
```

My code:

```
xtype: 'combo',
    width: 340,
    id: 'test',
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['text', 'color'],
        data: [
            ['Red', '#db4e4e'],
            ['Green', '#89b76e'],
            ['Blue', '#3c8787'],
        ]
    }),
    valueField: 'color',
    mode: 'local',
    editable: false,
    tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item" style="height: 20px; background-color:{color};"></div></tpl>',
    listeners: {
        select: {
            fn: function(combo, value) {
                Ext.getCmp('test').setStyle('background', value);
            }
        },
        scope: this
    }
```

I already tried:

```
this.setFieldStyle('background:#FF0000');
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem?

You can solve like this

**1)** [Ext.get()](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/source/ComponentMgr.html#method-Ext.ComponentMgr-get) returns a component by [id](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/output/Ext.Component.html#Ext.Component-id). For additional details see [Ext.util.MixedCollection.get](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/output/Ext.util.MixedCollection.html#Ext.util.MixedCollection-get).

```
Ext.get('ext-gen12').setStyle({
    background:'red'
})
```

**2)** [Ext.fly()](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext.Element-fly) gets the globally shared flyweight Element, with the passed node as the active element. Do not store a reference to this element - the dom node can be overwritten by other code.

```
Ext.fly('ext-gen12').setStyle({
   background:'yellow'
})
```

**Note**  `ext-gen12` is `id` of your `combobox` or any other `component` id. You can pass here `dom` element also.

I hope this will help  you to solve your problem.